# Region around a Path curve

Tags: android, graphics

How I can make a `Region` object around a curve?

I make quadratic Bezier curves with `Path` objects and, then, I draw them into a `Canvas` with the `drawPath()` function. I need to make 'nearby' `Region` objects around the curves.

Can you help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not android user but:

1. what about line width (may be called stroke width)

   - if you can set it to more than 1 pixel than it will draw your path wider
2. if you need exact shape then you need to transform your path to polygon

   - original beziers will became two
   - one shifted perpendicular to curve on one side
   - the other to opposite side.
   - close begin and end of the path with line, or curve

to get shifted control points just translate them in perpendicular direction from the curve
the shift size is half of the region width.